# How to pass the Column Names dynamically for Spanner batch.insert_or_update Python API

Tags: google-cloud-spanner

I'm reading the data from spanner using database.snapshot() and I'm trying to use the result set I got to perform batch.insert_or_update (In essence I'm performing Merge action using 2 spanner API calls). I could not find any documentation on how to set the columns using the result set from the database.snapshot(). I tried using a variable for columns option that's not working either. If I'm using a dataframe (reading from a sqlserver) and was able to set this dynamically using df.columns option. Appreciate if anyone can shed some light on this.

Here's what I've tried. I'm no expert in python, so please feel free to share your ideas if I'm doing something very dumb. I'm getting a list and converting this to a dataframe, if it seems strange please know that I'm trying to build a small generic function that can be run multi-thread and can be used for performing insert_update on any table.

````
```
sql_stmt = "select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4 from Table1 where Col1 > 1000 " 

spanner_client = spanner.Client()
instance = spanner_client.instance(instance_id)
database = instance.database(database_id)

with database.snapshot() as snapshot:
     results = snapshot.execute_sql(sql_stmt)

df = pd.DataFrame(results)
df.columns = results.metadata
columns_list = "('Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4')"
with database.batch() as batch:
      batch.insert_or_update(
      table=tablename,columns=columns_list,
      values=df.values.tolist())
```
````

Comment: Are you using the client library or are you calling directly the API?  If using the client library could you confirm the version you are using. and could you add the code of what you have tried to perform this?

Comment: @JoséSoní, I've updated the original question with the code I'm using. Thank you.

Comment: @JoséSoní, I made a mistake when setting the columns_list, if I remove the double quotes from the beginning and end it worked.

Comment: Could you publish your solution as an aswer, It can be helpful for fellow users and I'll be happy to upvote

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue and here's the corrected code. The column_list variable doesn't need quotes.

```
sql_stmt = "select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4 from Table1 where Col1 > 1000 " 

spanner_client = spanner.Client()
instance = spanner_client.instance(instance_id)
database = instance.database(database_id)

with database.snapshot() as snapshot:
     results = snapshot.execute_sql(sql_stmt)

df = pd.DataFrame(results)
df.columns = results.metadata
columns_list = ('Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4')
with database.batch() as batch:
      batch.insert_or_update(
      table=tablename,columns=columns_list,
      values=df.values.tolist())
```